# Keras: Cannot Import Name np_utils

Tags: python, keras

I'm using Python 2.7 and a Jupyter notebook to do some basic machine learning.  I'm following along with this tutorial:

http://machinelearningmastery.com/regression-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library-python/

I'm simply trying to import different things from Keras so I can run the tutorial.  Specifically, I do this:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
```

and it gets stuck at the first import, giving me a traceback of this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-aae66d0fdaee> in <module>()
----> 1 from keras.models import Sequential
      2 from keras.layers import Dense
      3 from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
      4 from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
      5 from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

/Users/newscred/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/__init__.py in <module>()
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
      2 
----> 3 from . import utils
      4 from . import activations
      5 from . import applications

/Users/newscred/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py in <module>()
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
----> 2 from . import np_utils
      3 from . import generic_utils
      4 from . import data_utils
      5 from . import io_utils

ImportError: cannot import name np_utils
```

I've Googled around but can't seem to find out why I'm running into this problem / how to fix.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What Keras version are you using?

Comment: Using 2.0.6 with TensorFlow backend

Comment: That's odd, Keras 2.0.6 includes that file, what do you have in 
/Users/newscred/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/utils/ ?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I have every folder up until utils (I have .../site-packages/keras but don't have a folder called utils there...

Comment: Then your keras installation is broken, how did you install it?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro just `pip install keras` :(

Comment: I just tried with that exact command and I did get the utils folder and the np_utils.py file. There is some detail you are leaving out. Just try reinstalling keras.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I do have Anaconda set up so maybe that's it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149018/discussion-between-bclayman-and-matias-valdenegro).

Comment: Is that possible you have multiple keras on your machine and you import the wrong one? Just `import keras; print keras.__path__; print keras.__version__` to make sure you have imported the correct one.

Comment: You can also separately install np_utils. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45149341/importerror-cannot-import-name-np-utils

Answer (score 3):

That tutorial was written on June 9th, 2016. Keras 2 was released in March 2017. Try installing the old version, using `pip install keras==1.2.2`.

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is how it worked for me.(I am using conda)
i created a virtualenv first with conda and then install tensorflow,theano and also future. make sure numpy is updated as well...

## steps to follow

```
conda install numpy

conda install future

conda install -c anaconda theano

conda install keras
```

now once all this is done. you can open jupyter from the same virtualenv or spyder(i was using spyder) or ipython notebook. this will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

import numpy in your python script before you import anything from Keras. I was facing the same issue, importing numpy before importing numpy utilities ( np_utils ) solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
pip install --upgrade --user keras
```

duplicate. Solution here

[ImportError: cannot import name np_utils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45149341/importerror-cannot-import-name-np-utils)