# ImportError: cannot import name np_utils

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to run the following [example](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/stateful_lstm.py) from keras

but I get this error:

```
ImportError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-50de27eea0f8> in <module>()   
      8 import numpy as np  
      9 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
---> 10 from keras.models import Sequential  
     11 from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM  
     12   

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/__init__.py in <module>()  
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import  
      2   
----> 3 from . import utils  
      4 from . import activations  
      5 from . import applications  

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py in <module>()  
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import  
----> 2 from . import np_utils  
      3 from . import generic_utils  
      4 from . import data_utils  
      5 from . import io_utils  

ImportError: cannot import name np_utils
```

I'm using Ubuntu and I installed keras with:

```
sudo pip install keras
```

This question was already asked but there was no answer:
[Keras: Cannot Import Name np_utils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45060150/keras-cannot-import-name-np-utils)

Comment: Was having the same problem, the fix that worked for me was closing the console and reopening a new one...

Comment: I had the same problem. In my case it was because Theano was trying to write a cache to a directory that it didn't have write access to. Using the Tensorflow backend instead sorted it for me.

Answer (score 45):

`np_utils` is a separate package (and a keras dependency - which doesn't get install with it). Can be installed using pip:

```
pip install np_utils
```

using - **Keras==2.0.6**

---

**Suggestion**:
For some odd (and still unknown) reasons, even after installing the import

```
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
```

didn't work - I had to restart the notebook (first restart even didn't work), and once it worked, I got stuck again for same import call (gave exception for `no module named tensorflow`) - as in utils there's another import `from . import conv_utils`, which required the tensorflow.

I did try installing tensorflow using pip install tensorflow gave:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow
>   (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for tensorflow

even this [gist](https://gist.github.com/87170360/856e30ca1fe8dd3a48b23efdaa417a5a) didn't work for me.

---

Finally, I [installed](http://devopspy.com/python/anaconda-centos-7/) Anaconda - which have all the scientific packages (numpy, scipy, scikit-learn,..) pre-installed. Installed keras:

```
conda install keras
```

Best thing was, it even installed tensorflow as its dependency.

Comment: Is this not possible without conda?

Comment: Where did you get that np_utils is a package? np_utils in Keras its a file in the utils folder, see at https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/np_utils.py

Comment: I’m the maintainer of np_utils on pypi and keras is not using it. Also, that was a relative import, so it’s internal to keras.

Comment: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.utils.np_utils'"

Answer (score 38):

For **keras > 2.0**, please use `from keras.utils import to_categorical` instead.

Example of usage will be `to_categorical(y, num_classes=None)`

Answer (score 12):

They moved everything to just utils, so if you are using tf 2.x or higher version of keras it is just `tf.keras.utils` or `keras.utils`.

So for example:
`keras.utils.np_utils.to_categorical` -> `keras.utils.to_categorical`

Comment: This solution was already proposed in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50933790/6682517).

Answer (score 9):

I was actually having similar issue while using

```py
from keras.utils import to_categorical
```

But I managed to solve it with:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
```

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same issue. You need to do `pip install np_utils` and then restart your terminal. Make sure everything is up to date.

Answer (score 4):

Try importing `numpy` before you import something from `keras` (I see that you have already done so, am adding this just to document the solution which worked for me). I faced the same error and when I tried:

```
import numpy as np
from __future__ import absolute_import
#Anything from keras
```

It seemed to work just fine with me. Try installing the latest stable packages of `future` and `numpy` beforehand through:

```
pip install future
pip install numpy
```

Sometimes its possible that *conda* and other installations of python might be interfering with each other. I had everything managed through brew beforehand, but when I installed *conda* many of the packages which I previously installed gave me an import error (because of the `PYTHONPATH` variable).

Answer (score 2):

I had to install tensorflow to solve this problem.
(From virtualenv):

```
 pip install tensorflow
```

Comment: This worked for me, apparently Keras doesn't install tensorflow or theano by default.

Answer (score 1):

from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import tf_utils
ImportError: cannot import name 'tf_utils'

**`pip install keras==2.1.5 -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple`**

https://blog.csdn.net/CLOUD_J/article/details/103101247

Answer (score 1):

This works in Google Colab:

```
import tensorflow as tf

y_train=tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train,num_classes=7)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
from keras import utils

utils.to_categorical(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import np_utils
```

Comment: It seems like the right way to import `np_utils` has evolved over time. To make this answer more useful, can you mention what version of tf you are using?

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in a build system:

- Keras throwing: ImportError: cannot import name np_utils
- But also tensorflow assertion failure: AttributeError: type object 'NewBase' has no attribute 'is_abstract'

The problem in my case was the build environment, for some reason I didn't investigate, had an old six version (six 1.5.0) (compared to my local env). The issue was solved by installing the most recent six version (1.11.0 when writing this).

`pip install six -U`

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the old version using Anaconda:

```
conda install tensorflow-gpu==1.2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Open Anaconda Prompt --> Write this command : **conda install keras**



(base) C:\>conda `enter code here`install keras
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\sinem.secgin\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - keras


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    _tflow_select-2.3.0        |              mkl           3 KB
    absl-py-0.7.1              |           py37_0         158 KB
    astor-0.7.1                |           py37_0          44 KB
    ca-certificates-2019.5.15  |                0         166 KB
    certifi-2019.6.16          |           py37_0         155 KB
    conda-4.7.5                |           py37_0         3.0 MB
    conda-package-handling-1.3.10|           py37_0         280 KB
    gast-0.2.2                 |           py37_0         138 KB
    grpcio-1.16.1              |   py37h351948d_1         947 KB
    keras-2.2.4                |                0           5 KB
    keras-applications-1.0.8   |             py_0          33 KB
    keras-base-2.2.4           |           py37_0         489 KB
    keras-preprocessing-1.1.0  |             py_1          36 KB
    libmklml-2019.0.3          |                0        21.4 MB
    libprotobuf-3.8.0          |       h7bd577a_0         2.2 MB
    markdown-3.1.1             |           py37_0         132 KB
    mock-3.0.5                 |           py37_0          47 KB
    openssl-1.1.1c             |       he774522_1         5.7 MB
    protobuf-3.8.0             |   py37h33f27b4_0         581 KB
    tensorboard-1.13.1         |   py37h33f27b4_0         3.3 MB
    tensorflow-1.13.1          |mkl_py37h9463c59_0           4 KB
    tensorflow-base-1.13.1     |mkl_py37hcaf7020_0        49.4 MB
    tensorflow-estimator-1.13.0|             py_0         205 KB
    termcolor-1.1.0            |           py37_1           7 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        88.4 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  _tflow_select      pkgs/main/win-64::_tflow_select-2.3.0-mkl
  absl-py            pkgs/main/win-64::absl-py-0.7.1-py37_0
  astor              pkgs/main/win-64::astor-0.7.1-py37_0
  conda-package-han~ pkgs/main/win-64::conda-package-handling-1.3.10-py37_0
  gast               pkgs/main/win-64::gast-0.2.2-py37_0
  grpcio             pkgs/main/win-64::grpcio-1.16.1-py37h351948d_1
  keras              pkgs/main/win-64::keras-2.2.4-0
  keras-applications pkgs/main/noarch::keras-applications-1.0.8-py_0
  keras-base         pkgs/main/win-64::keras-base-2.2.4-py37_0
  keras-preprocessi~ pkgs/main/noarch::keras-preprocessing-1.1.0-py_1
  libmklml           pkgs/main/win-64::libmklml-2019.0.3-0
  libprotobuf        pkgs/main/win-64::libprotobuf-3.8.0-h7bd577a_0
  markdown           pkgs/main/win-64::markdown-3.1.1-py37_0
  mock               pkgs/main/win-64::mock-3.0.5-py37_0
  protobuf           pkgs/main/win-64::protobuf-3.8.0-py37h33f27b4_0
  tensorboard        pkgs/main/win-64::tensorboard-1.13.1-py37h33f27b4_0
  tensorflow         pkgs/main/win-64::tensorflow-1.13.1-mkl_py37h9463c59_0
  tensorflow-base    pkgs/main/win-64::tensorflow-base-1.13.1-mkl_py37hcaf7020_0
  tensorflow-estima~ pkgs/main/noarch::tensorflow-estimator-1.13.0-py_0
  termcolor          pkgs/main/win-64::termcolor-1.1.0-py37_1

Proceed ([y]/n)? y
Y
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `TensorFlow` backend with `Keras` make sure your keras.json file states its backend is Tensorflow. The code below worked for me:

```
import os
os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND']='tensorflow'
#Anything from keras
```

Cheers hope I helped somebody. 
OBS: I was using Anaconda and Spyder.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to have different solutions depending on the situation. Here's yet another solution that helped me when I had those exact symptoms:

```
pip install enum34
```

Installing np_utils, future or a different version of numpy or Theano didn't help for me. The problem was due to Keras that use enum, that only exists in Python3. Enum34 is a backport of Python3's enum to Python2.

I was using:

- python2.7
- Keras==2.3.0
- Theano==1.0.4 as a backend

Answer (score 0):

In tf 2.x or higher, Keras has been packed into TensorFlow, you now call everything from TensorFlow.
np_utils has been moved to util you can simply use it by doing:

```
tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(
y, num_classes=None, dtype='float32'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

this work for me keras version (2.13.1)

```
from keras import utils

Y_train = utils.to_categorical(y_train, n_classes)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me now

`from keras.src.utils.np_utils import to_categorical`

Answer (score 0):

For me, np_utils can be accessed by:

```
from keras.src.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
```

to get a specific package.